# Format Exception was unhandled...?

Tags: c#, arrays, class, counter, formatexception

My teacher provided me code to use to create a program, but, when I run it, it gives me 'FormatException was unhandled'. It suggests for me to convert a string to DateTime, but that has nothing to do with the code. I really can't pinpoint where the issue is. I'm using C#, through Microsoft Visual Studio, if that's any help.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    student[] students = new student[5];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        students[i] = new student();
        try
        {
            int counter = 0; //array index counter
            students[counter].personName = txtName.Text;
            students[counter].personGPA = Convert.ToDouble(txtGPA.Text);

            txtDisplay.Text += "Name: " + students[counter].Name + "\r\n GPA: " + students[counter].GPA.ToString();
            counter++; //increment the array index counter by 1
            txtName.Text = string.Empty;
            txtGPA.Text = string.Empty;
            txtName.Focus();
        } //end of code for the try block
        catch (ArgumentException) //GPA is out of range
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a proper GPA");
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfRangeException) //array is full
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are already 5 students.");
        }
    }
}

class student
{
    public String personName;
    public Double personGPA;

    public string Name
    {
       // get;
        //set; 
        get { return personName; }
        set { personName = value; }
    }

    public double GPA
    {
        //get;
        //set;
        get {return personGPA; }
        set { personGPA = value; }
    }        
}
```

Comment: at which line specifically does the error occur

Comment: I suspect it's actually failing at `Convert.ToDouble(txtGPA.Text)`... what is the value of `txtGPA.Text`?

Comment: it happens at students[counter].personGPA = Convert.ToDouble(txtGPA.Text);

Comment: So as @JonSkeet said, whats the value  you've entered?

Comment: it's supposed to be set equal to whatever the user types into the textbox

Comment: yes but give us an example of the text you entered that fails

Comment: I tried, for instance, 'Name' for txtName and '2' for txtGPA and it returned the error

Comment: @Naima Can you please put a breakpoint there and inspect the value? It definitely will not fail for `2`.

Comment: Im thinking that maybe the thing you think is txtGPA is maybe on the label not the text box to enter

Comment: @Rob, when I put in a breakpoint and step into it, it says that it's equal to 2, but, outside of the breakpoint (when the program runs fully) it crashes

Comment: @BugFinder just checked and both of my textboxes are appropriately named- txtGPA and txtName

Comment: @Rob, when the program crashes, the watch shows that the text = " ", if that's any help

Comment: so thats telling you where you put 2 wasnt the box you though it was

Comment: @Naima After a closer look, it's because you're doing a loop (5 times), but you're clearing the text after the first iteration. `txtGPA.Text = string.Empty;`. Those clears should be outside the loop, if not removed altogether.

Comment: good spot, no chance is given to allow further entries

Comment: @Rob, while it doesn't crash when i took out the code to clear the text, i need to be able to input up to five names and GPAs into the txtDisplay. is there any way to 'reset' the text to allow new names and GPAs to be put in the textboxes?

Comment: pulling the txtGPA.Text = string.Empty outside of the for loop just made the same entry (Name: Name GPA: 2) repeat five lines on my txtDisplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's have a look:

```
 for (...) {
   ...
   students[counter].personGPA = Convert.ToDouble(txtGPA.Text);
   ...
   txtGPA.Text = string.Empty;
```

you've *parsed* `txtGPA.Text` then *clear* it and try to *parse again* (since the code is within the *for loop*). An *empty* value can't be converted into `double` and you have the exception thrown.

Probably, you want to *pull* all the values from the loop:

```
 double gpa = Convert.ToDouble(txtGPA.Text); 
 txtGPA.Text = String.Empty;

 for (...) {
   ... 
   students[counter].personGPA = gpa;
```

please note, that `students[counter]` is still very suspicious code since `counter` is not a *loop variable* (that's `i`).

Comment: completing the for loop by itself (ending after new student();) and clearing the textboxes outside of the try catch fixed it - thank you all for your help!